# find_all returns none using beautifulSoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Beautifulsoup, and I am following a tuto to learn it. Using the following code, I am supposed to get list of salaries; however, I get none or [] value. The link is https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/5IwIKSerP7cr-Outdoor-Sales-Representative-Cairo-Egypt

```
     for i in range(len(job_titles)):
     list_jobs.append(job_titles[i].text)
     links.append(job_titles[i].find("a").attrs["href"])
     list_companies.append(company_names[i].text)
     list_locations.append(locations[i].text)
     list_skills.append(job_skills[i].text)

     for link in links:
         result = requests.get(link)
         #print(result.text)
         src =result.content

         soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
         salaries = soup.find('span' , {'class' : 'css-4xky9y'})
         print(salaries)
         #list_salaries.append(salaries)
```

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: Here is the link [link](https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/5IwIKSerP7cr-Outdoor-Sales-Representative-Cairo-Egypt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional details about salary (min/max etc.) is stored inside the page in JavaScript. To parse it you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests

links = [
    "https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/5IwIKSerP7cr-Outdoor-Sales-Representative-Cairo-Egypt"
]


for link in links:
    result = requests.get(link)

    data = re.search(r"Wuzzuf\.initialStoreState = (\{.*\})", result.text)
    data = json.loads(data.group(1))

    # uncomment this line to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for job in data["entities"]["job"]["collection"].values():
        salary = job["attributes"]["salary"]
        print(
            "Min: {} Max: {} Additional Details: {}".format(
                salary["min"], salary["max"], salary["additionalDetails"]
            )
        )
        break
```

Prints:

```
Min: None Max: None Additional Details: Attractive Commission
```